# Me gustaría añadir el input del number a la derecha del "send with time out"

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A la derecha del timeout... me gustaría que se mostrase el input que tengo debajo.
Es un input que está escondido y que solo aparece cuando marco su correspondiente checkbox.

Adjunto código también:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 input-group input-group-sm">
                <input class="form-check-input" id="node-input-sendFullArray" type="checkbox" name="checkeo"> <i class="fa fa-send"></i> Send full array
                <label class="form-check-label" for="sendFullArray"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 input-group input-group-sm">
                <input class="form-check-input" id="node-input-sendRandomElement" type="checkbox" name="checkeo"> <i class="fa fa-random"></i> Send random element
                <label class="form-check-label" for="sendRandomElement"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 input-group input-group-sm">
                <input class="form-check-input" id="node-input-sendWithTimeOut" type="checkbox" name="checkeo" onchange="showNumber()"> <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Send with timeout
                <label class="form-check-label" for="sendWithTimeOut"></label>
                <div id="content" style="display: none;">

                    <input class="form-check-input" id="node-input-seconds" type="number" min="1" max="99" name="checkeo" style="width: 15%;"> </i> seconds
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="seconds">
                    
                </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Código que muestra el contador:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showNumber() {
        check = document.getElementById("node-input-sendWithTimeOut");
        element = document.getElementById("content");
        if (check.checked) {
            element.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            element.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: En vez de `<div>` usa una etiqueta [en línea](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) como `<span>`.

Comment: Adjunto un estracto más de código que quizás influye en el estilo, edito arriba. Gracias.

Comment: Cuando asignas `block` a la propiedad `display`, automáticamente lo estás colocando abajo. Cambia por `inline-block`.

Comment: Igual, se sigue manteniendo abajo. Necesitas que te muestre algo más de código? Gracias de nuevo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te dije en comentarios, con `block` haces que el elemento se coloque abajo y necesitas cambiar por `inline-block`. Prueba con este fragmento de código para ver que funciona correctamente:

```js
function showNumber() {
    check = document.getElementById("node-input-sendWithTimeOut");
    element = document.getElementById("content");
    if (check.checked) {
        element.style.display = 'inline-block';
    } else {
        element.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 input-group input-group-sm">
                <input class="form-check-input" id="node-input-sendFullArray" type="checkbox" name="checkeo"> <i class="fa fa-send"></i> Send full array
                <label class="form-check-label" for="sendFullArray"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 input-group input-group-sm">
                <input class="form-check-input" id="node-input-sendRandomElement" type="checkbox" name="checkeo"> <i class="fa fa-random"></i> Send random element
                <label class="form-check-label" for="sendRandomElement"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 input-group input-group-sm">
                <input class="form-check-input" id="node-input-sendWithTimeOut" type="checkbox" name="checkeo" onchange="showNumber()"> <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Send with timeout
                <label class="form-check-label" for="sendWithTimeOut"></label>
                <div id="content" style="display: none;">

                    <input class="form-check-input" id="node-input-seconds" type="number" min="1" max="99" name="checkeo" style="width: 15%;"> </i> seconds
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="seconds">
                    
                </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Si aún se sigue manteniendo abajo, debes revisar los estilos CSS, probablemente tengas una regla que force el elemento (un hijo o un previo) a comportarse como bloque. Te sugiero checar `#node-input-sendWithTimeOut`, `#content` y `#node-input-seconds`.

Finalmente, algunas recomendaciones:

- No uses estilos en línea: `<div id="content" style="display: none;">`, mejor usa una clase para ocultar `<div id="content" class="oculto">` y con Javascript puedes quitar la clase para que se muestre y agregarla para volver a ocultar
- No uses eventos en línea: `<input ... name="checkeo" onclick="showNumber()">`, es mejor obtener el elemento y asignar el evento desde Javascript
- Las etiquetas `<label>` son útiles para ayudar a acceder al campo al que están relacionadas y, si están vacías, no tiene sentido que las uses. Además, el atributo `for` debe contener ID de elemento al que están asociadas

Aplicando estas recomendaciones. tu código quedaría más o menos así:

```js
// Obtener checkbox
let check = document.querySelector('#node-input-sendWithTimeOut');
// Asignar evento
check.addEventListener('change', showNumber);

function showNumber() {
    element = document.getElementById("content");
    // Check se definió fuera de la función
    if (check.checked) {
        // Quitar clase para que se pueda mostrar
        element.classList.remove('oculto');
    } else {
        // Agregar clase para ocultar
        element.classList.add('oculto');
    }
}
```

```css
#content {
    display: inline-block;
}
#content.oculto {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 input-group input-group-sm">
                <input class="form-check-input" id="node-input-sendFullArray" type="checkbox" name="checkeo"> 
                <label class="form-check-label" for="node-input-sendFullArray">
                    <i class="fa fa-send"></i> Send full array
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 input-group input-group-sm">
                <input class="form-check-input" id="node-input-sendRandomElement" type="checkbox" name="checkeo"> 
                <label class="form-check-label" for="node-input-sendRandomElement">
                    <i class="fa fa-random"></i> Send random element
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 input-group input-group-sm">
                <input class="form-check-input" id="node-input-sendWithTimeOut" type="checkbox" name="checkeo"> 
                <label class="form-check-label" for="node-input-sendWithTimeOut">
                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Send with timeout
                </label>
                <div id="content" class="oculto">

                    <input class="form-check-input" id="node-input-seconds" type="number" min="1" max="99" name="checkeo" style="width: 15%;"> 
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="node-input-seconds">
                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> seconds
                </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Ya está como quería, mil gracias de verdad. Un saludo, amigo.

Comment: Hola @Andrés si esta respuesta te ayudó, considera marcarla como aceptada, revisa [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)